# How to bound $\int_{|x-y|=\epsilon} \frac{\partial f}{\partial n} dS(y)$? Here $n$ is the outer normal vector and $S$ is the surface measure.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider $y \in \mathbb R^2$, how can I bound the integral $$\int_{|x-y|=\epsilon} \frac{\partial f}{\partial n} dS(y)$$ Here, $n$ is the outer normal vector and $S$ is the surface measure.

My intuition says it's bounded by $C\epsilon$ but don't know how to prove this.

Comment: That should be the integral of $\Delta f(y)$ over $|x-y|\le\epsilon$. If you have a bound on the Laplacian of $f$ in that sphere, that should give your bound.

Comment: @robjohn Actually, that's where it comes from. I don't know the bound about the Laplacian and that's why I used divergence theorem to see the bound of this integral.

Comment: Then do you have a bound on $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}$? There needs to be more information to give an answer.

Comment: @robjohn Do you think $f$ in Schwartz space suffices?

Comment: That definitely puts a bound on both $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}$ and the Laplacian. With a bound on the Laplacian, the integral is $O\!\left(\epsilon^2\right)$

Comment: @robjohn Not $O(\epsilon)?$. $y \in \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: It's the integral of $\Delta f$ over the disc of radius $\epsilon$, which has area $O\!\left(\epsilon^2\right)$.